# cross-referencing acronyms not displayed in the text with

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries, acronyms

I use glossaries and define besides standard acronyms also some acronyms like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor} 

\definecolor{navy}{RGB}{0,0,128}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=navy,
    anchorcolor=black,
    urlcolor=navy
]{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{P2P}{
    type=\acronymtype, 
    name={P2P}, 
    description={Peer-to-Peer}, 
    first={Peer-to-Peer (P2P)}, 
    see=[\glossaryname:]{Peer-to-Peer}
}
\newglossaryentry{Peer-to-Peer}{
    name={Peer-to-Peer},
    description={Eine direkte Kommunikation zwischen zwei Teilnehmern}
}

\newglossaryentry{Plug-in}{
    name={Plug-in},
    description={Ein Softwaremodul, das zur Laufzeit eingebunden werden kann und damit die Funktionalität eines Systems erweitert}
}

\newacronym{DIN}{DIN}{Deutsches Institut für Normung}


\newcommand*\acrshortlong[2][]{\glslink[#1]{#2}{\glsentryshort{#2} (\glsentrylong{#2})}}

\begin{document}

Works as expected:

gls: \gls{Plug-in}

gls: \gls{DIN}

acrshort: \acrshort{DIN}

acrshortlong: \acrshortlong{DIN}

gls: \gls{Peer-to-Peer}

Not as expected:

acrshort: \acrshort{P2P}

acrshortlong: \acrshortlong{P2P}

\glossarystyle{altlist}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\glossarystyle{altlist}
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the \acr... commands dont work as expected with acronyms defined via \newglossaryentry with type=\acronymtype

Anyone an idea how to get these cross-referencing acronyms also working as expected?

Comment: `\newacronym` also sets the `long` and `short` keys, which are referenced by `\glsentrylong` and `\glsentryshort`. However, why don't you you just use `\newacronym[see={[\glossaryname:]{Peer-to-Peer}}]{P2P}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Sometimes are the easier solutions the better ones :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Converting comment into an answer.)

Commands like `\glsentrylong` and `\glsentryshort` access the `long` and `short` keys. These keys (and their plural versions) are set by `\newacronym` but have to be explicitly set, if required, when using `\newglossaryentry`. However in this case it's simpler to just use the optional argument of `\newacronym` to set the cross-referencing information:

```
\newacronym[see={[\glossaryname:]{Peer-to-Peer}}]{P2P}{P2P}{Peer-to-Peer}
```